# How to remove the 90 km/h speed limit on Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

Can somebody explain how to remove the 90 km/h speed limit on Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can remove the speed limiter from the gameplay settings by unticking "Truck Speed Limiter":

[image: gameplay settings]

You need patch 1.4.1 or higher to use this setting.

Also note that **external jobs provided by World of Trucks force the speed limiter on** regardless of your preferences.

If you're using an earlier patch, there are mods that let you do this:

- http://euro-truck-simulator-2-no-speed-limit-mod.en.softonic.com/
- http://ets2mods.org/2013/03/no-speed-limit/

Comment: Also note: from everything I've heard, going much faster than 90 on most roads will land you in a ditch. Watch your speed, kids!

Comment: Adds realism ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, when doing a WoT External Contract mission, you are not allowed to remove the speed limit.

Comment: Untick that checkbox but still limit at 90 while having container behind the truck.